# Is this the safest way of defining the global precision?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

By restricting

```
 $MinPrecision = $MaxPrecision = $MaxExtraPrecision = 17
```

and adding extra precision to any real number

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
     s_String /; 
       StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
        Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> 
      s <> "`17." &);
```

as long as i have a real number i get the correct results

[image]

My question is that are there any side effects by restricting MinPrecision, MaxPrecision, and MaxExtraPrecision to the desired precision?

Comment: What's the goal here?

Comment: @user6014 to put a minimal effort to always have a consistent precision regardless of how many functions you have (instead of SetPrecision for every function). This solves many problems associated with WorkingPrecision errors.